# How to cp files from sources to destination without using alias or non-alias and without getting confirmation/prompts?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rpm, command

```
$ cp /source/* /destination/ 
cp: overwrite `/destination/file1.conf`
```

Aim is to copy files from source to destination without getting prompt or using non-alias(/) method.

Answer (score 2):

**Command Without Alias**

Any unix command can be prefixed with `\` to get the non-alias version.

**With Alias**

```
#-(0) :: /dev/shm/test2 > ls
total 0
-rw-------. 1 root 0 Feb 24 16:29 a
-rw-------. 1 root 0 Feb 24 16:29 b
-rw-------. 1 root 0 Feb 24 16:29 c
-rw-------. 1 root 0 Feb 24 16:29 d
```

**Without Alias**

```
#-(0) :: /dev/shm/test2 > \ls
a  b  c  d
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "using unalias method", but if you read the `cp` man page, you can learn about

```
-n, --no-clobber
          do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
```

and

```
-u, --update
          copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the
          destination file or when the destination file is missing
```

so you would have two ways to avoid the prompt. You need to decide which method is better suited for your purposes.

Comment: it might be that he uses a shell where cp is already alias to cp -i or something like that (similiar to what Aaron answered)